# How to list all taxonomy terms in a vocabulary followed by associated node titles in Views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to list all of the taxonomy terms from a vocabulary in views and have the node title of all of the nodes that have that term associated with them listed under each term. For example, I have a vocabulary of State names. The various nodes have a term reference field to link the node with a state. I then want to create a view that will show the state name followed by the nodes with that state name, then the next state name etc. I can create a taxonomy view that lists all of the state names, but can't find a way to add the node titles under each state name. I am converting an existing non-Drupal site to Drupal 7.

Here is a link to the current page that I want to make happen in Drupal. It shows the states following by what would be the node titles for each state.

http://www.cbfisk.com/do/DisplayInstrumentList/filter/geographic

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view in following way,

```
1. create a new view to show taxonomy terms of type state 
2. Then click relationship under advanced, and choose 'Taxonomy term: Content with term'
3. Then under 'fields' add ' Content: Title' as new field, by keeping relationship 'node'
4. Under 'format' choose HTML list (or table), and set  Taxonomy term: Name  as grouping   field
5. You can choose 'exclude from display' option for field  Taxonomy term: Name
```

Then you will get the output in desired format as below,
[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly and is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome, if it is worked mark it as answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed your reply. I'm new to this and don't know how to "mark it as an answer." Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: please checkout faq http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask